# Finding kinetic friction coefficient

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

> A box is thrown up an incline with degree $\alpha$. the kinetic-friction coefficient is $\mu_k$. the body returns back to its start point.
>
> a. prove $\frac{t_{down}^2}{t_{up}^2}=\frac{a_{up}}{a_{down}}$.
>
> b. suppose time of getting up the incline is half of the time needed for getting down it, find $\mu_k$

With `a`, I had no problem proving it, but with `b` I have a problem.

Using `a` we get 
$$a_{up}=-4\cdot a_{down}$$ 
and after substituting in Newton's second law,
$$ma=\sum F_x=F-mg\cos\alpha-f_k$$ 
I got 
$$F=-30m\sin\alpha+50\mu_{k}m\cos\alpha$$ $$\beta=-30\sin\alpha+50\mu_{k}\cos\alpha-10\sin\alpha-10\mu_{k}\cos\alpha=-40\sin\alpha+40\mu_{k}\cos\alpha\\\gamma=10\left(\sin\alpha-\mu_{k}\cos\alpha\right)$$

We also know that (using $f_k$ from $\sum F_x$) 
$$\mu_k=\frac{f_k}{N}=\frac{-30m\sin\alpha+50\mu_{k}m\cos\alpha-40m\sin\alpha+40m\mu_{k}\cos\alpha-mg\sin\alpha}{mg\cos\alpha}\\
=\frac{-80m\sin\alpha+90\mu_k\cos\alpha}{10m\cos\alpha}$$ 
and it follows that 
$$\mu_k=tan\alpha \quad{\rm or}\quad \alpha=90^\circ$$ 
Both cases are impossible (in one $\mu_k$ cannot be found and in another the incline is just a wall). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $t_{u}=t_{d}/2\to \frac{t_d}{\frac12t_u}=2\frac{t_d}{t_d}=2=\frac{a^2_u}{a^2_d}\to a_u=\pm\sqrt{2}a_d$, right?

Comment: The question says "whose tangent is $\alpha$", but in your work you treat it as if the *angle* relative to horizontal is $\alpha$. Should we read "tangent" as "angle" here?

Comment: yes. $\alpha$ is the angle of the incline.

Comment: I got hung up on a portion from the text of the problem. "A box is thrown up an incline **whose tangent is $\alpha$**."  I don't know why but from this I understand that the angle of the incline is $\beta$ and $\tan{\alpha}=\beta$. Which in this case $\mu_{k}=\alpha$.